# Cauchy Problem with characteristics method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have this Cauchy Problem

$
\begin{cases} 
u_{t} +(1-2u)u_{x} &= 0 \\
u(0,x)&= arctg(x)
\end{cases}
$

and i found this solution written in implicit form

$
\begin{cases} 
u(t,x) &= arctg(r(t,x)) \\
x(t,r) &= (1-2arctg(r))t + r
\end{cases}
$

while the solution is
$ u(t,x)=arctg(\dfrac{x-t}{1-2t}) $

Can anyone tell me what i did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you get that was the correct solution? If you check whether that solution holds the Cauchy problem you get,

$$ u_t = \frac{2x-1}{(1-2t)^2+(x+t)^2}, \quad u_x = \frac{t(2t-1)}{(1-2t)^2+(x+t)^2}, $$

and introduced into the equation gives,

$$ u_t + (1-2u)u_x = \frac{1}{(1-2t)^2+(x+t)^2}\left( 2x-1+t(2t-1)\left[ 1-2\arctan\left(\frac{x-t}{1-2t}\right) \right] \right), $$

which I don't see why that should trivially be zero. Meanwhile your solution does hold the Cauchy problem!

$$ u_t = \frac{r_t}{1+r^2}, \quad u_x = \frac{r_x}{1+r^2}, $$

$$ r_t = (1+r^2)\frac{1-2\arctan(r)}{2t-1}, \quad r_x = \frac{1+r^2}{1-2t}, $$

$$ \Rightarrow \quad u_t + (1-2u)u_x = (1-2\arctan(r))\frac{1}{2t-1-r^2} + (1-2\arctan(r))\frac{1}{1+r^2-2t}\equiv 0.  $$

Also $r(0,x) = x$ and thus $u(0,x) = \arctan(r(0,x))=\arctan(x)$.

I apologize if I made any mistake with the computations. Hope it helps!